# Generate names on .ll file

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I am new to llvm and I am trying to generate .ll file using below command.

`clang -S -O0 -emit-llvm 1.c`

But in the generated 1.ll file, basic blocks & instructions have no name.So when I try to print names of basic blocks using `basicblock.getName()` in my code it will print nothing. Can someone please help me to generate names on .ll file?

Comment: Can you show an example of the generated IR?

Comment: `-emit-llvm` generates named instructions and blocks when I run it. For `int main(){return 0;}` I get a function named main, a block named entry and an instruction named retval, plus some unnamed things. What names do you expect to see that you don't see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the Clang code generator (the part that creates the LLVM IR) only name the LLVM registers if clang itself is compiled in debug mode.

Be aware that the names are not relevant for the semantics of the program, so aren't really needed.